# How to prove $Pr\{(A \cap \overline{B})\cup (\overline{A} \cap B)\} = Pr(A) + Pr(B) − 2 Pr(A \cap B)$

Tags: probability

I've managed to expand the left side to $$Pr(A \cap \overline{B}) + Pr(\overline{A} \cap B) - Pr((A \cap \overline{B})\cap (\overline{A} \cap B)) $$
and from there to $$ \{Pr(A) * Pr(\overline{B}|A)\} + \{(1-Pr(A)) * Pr(B|\overline{A})\} - Pr(A \cap \overline{B}) * Pr\{(\overline{A} \cap B)|(A \cap \overline{B})\}$$
and even further to 
$$\{Pr(A) * \frac{Pr(A \cap \overline{B})}{Pr(A)}\} * \Big\{\frac{Pr(A \cap \overline{B})-Pr\{(\overline{A} \cap B) \cap (A \cap \overline{B})\}}{Pr(A \cap \overline{B})}\Big\} +  \{(1-Pr(A)) * \frac{Pr( \overline{A} \cap B)}{1-Pr(A)}\}$$
...But from there I am lost. I am not given events A and B are independent. Are there any properties I am missing? I am just using the fact that $$Pr(A \cup B) = Pr(A) + Pr(B) - Pr(A \cap B)$$ and  $$Pr(A \cap B) = Pr(A) + Pr(B) - Pr(A \cup B)$$
and
$$Pr(A|B) = \frac{Pr(A \cap B)}{Pr(B)}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use some identities of intersection and union of sets. Doing a Venn diagram always helps you see where to go. Anyway, you have:
$$Pr(A \cap \overline{B}) + Pr(\overline{A} \cap B) - Pr((A \cap \overline{B})\cap (\overline{A} \cap B)) $$

the third term is zero since it's the intersection of two sets and their complements.

Next you have

$$Pr(A \cap \overline{B}) = Pr(A) + Pr(\overline{B}) - Pr(A \cup \overline B) $$

$$ = Pr(A) + Pr(\overline B) - Pr(\overline B \cup (A\cap B))$$

$$=Pr(A)+ Pr(\overline B) - [Pr(\overline B) + Pr(A \cap B) - Pr(\overline B \cap (A \cap B))] $$

last term inside the square brackets is zero since $A \cap B$ is inside $B$.

Finally you get:

$$ = Pr(A) - Pr(A \cap B)$$

You can do the same with $ Pr(\overline{A} \cap B) $ and put all together.

Just do a simple Venn diagram and you will see that the problem reduces to try to prove what you intuitively see on paper.

Answer (score 0):

Probability is a kind of measure of the size of subsets of the underlying sample space. If you can show that you count the same elements of each set the same number of times you can prove the relation. An element of the sample space must be in exactly one of the following sets: $A \cap B$, $A \cap \overline{B}$, $\overline{A} \cap B$, $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$. Elements of the first set are counted 0 times on the LHS and 1+1-2=0 times on the RHS, tick. Elements of the second and third sets are each counted once on each side, tick and elements of the fourth set aren't counted at all, tick.